# What is loc parameter in GPD distribution in POT package for R?

Tags: r, extreme-value

I fitted the Generalized Pareto distribution (GPD) using the `POT` package in `R`.

The fitted object provides shape and scale parameters, but not the location parameter. I need it to evaluate the quantile function with `qgpd(p, loc = 0, scale = 1, shape = 0, lower.tail = TRUE, lambda = 0)`.

I am sure this is very basic question (maybe it is mean value, but from which values - all, or only that which are bigger than threshold?) but I am begginer in this area and help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The location parameter is the `threshold` parameter that you provide to the `fitgpd` function. For example

```
library(POT)
set.seed(345)
x   <- rgpd(2000, 1, 2, 0.25)
fit <- fitgpd(x, threshold = 1)
fit$fitted.values
#    scale     shape 
#2.0501190 0.2471565
```

See equations (2.3) and (2.4) in the package [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/POT/vignettes/POT.pdf) for details on the model.